# How to define the link color of a selected hyperlink?

Tags: css

I want the link color to be blue after click it, but not all visited links, not active link not hover link. Why it doesn't work when I use a:selected in my CSS?

Comment: Because there isn't a `:selected` pseudo-class. It's not very clear what you mean by selected.

Comment: why not clear? I want change color of the link which I just clicked. More offten use in a menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to modify the color of something after you click it and have that change stick, you need JavaScript. There isn't any pseudo-class in CSS that handles this.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the link in a span with a class that changes the visited color to blue. This way you get the effect only on links you wrap in the new span.

Comment: It's already in a div, but it is a <ul><li>aa</li></ul> structure

Comment: Add the class to the the div tag then--or any other parent element. the class needs to just define the visited property to give the color blue, and the class can be used whenever and only wherever you want the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using ':visited' selector?

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:visited{color:blue;}
```

:active is when it's been clicked
:hover on ... hover
:link for non visited links
:focus if it has focus
and if it's for specific links just add a class

```
<a href="#" class="special">Special Link</a>

.special:visited{color:blue;}
```